# I cannot install „Linter pylint” in Visual Studio Code. I use Python 3.9

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Help!

I cannot install „Linter pylint” in Visual Studio Code. I use Python 3.9 and Windows 10.

Python is installed in C:\Program Files\Python39

When I start the Ide, it tells me “Linter pyling is not installed. Source: Python (Extension) [Install / Select Linter / Do not show again]”.

When I select “Install” it finds cached files it throws me the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte 
(sitecustomize.py, line 21)
WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte 
(sitecustomize.py, line 21)
 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe' 
'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' 
prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
```

I've changed in the code my real name to XXX because it shows my full first and last name.

However, pylint works ok on my laptop and Visual Studio Code. I've already checked several other topics and also googled this issue. However, I was unable to resolve this.

Is this an issue with the PATH?

I also tried to install pylint via the CMD and had Visual Studio Code close. I get the following error messages:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\XXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprs1z79cr'
         cwd: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-50w37pyv\lazy-object-proxy_19a2f4b71f224fe7bc87991bc2a8cf52
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-inoke7l2\lazy_object_proxy.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-inoke7l2\lazy_object_proxy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-inoke7l2\lazy_object_proxy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-inoke7l2\lazy_object_proxy.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-inoke7l2\lazy_object_proxy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-inoke7l2\lazy_object_proxy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-inoke7l2\lazy_object_proxy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-inoke7l2\lazy_object_proxy.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\XXXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprs1z79cr' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thank you!

Comment: How did you install "Pylint" manually? and Could you use pip to install other modules? Please try to install the required modules using other versions of Python.

Comment: I use "pip install pylint". It seems that the package "wheel" was missing and I run "pip install wheel". Now I was able to install "pylint". That's strange, because my laptop had "wheel" installed.

Anyway, how can I upvote your comment? You helped me to resolve the issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you right click under your folders on Visual Studio Code, Open Integrated Terminal, and check if pip is installed first. If pip is not installed, update the package list using the command:

```
sudo apt update
```

and then install pip with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

or

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

and then install pylint:

```
sudo pip-3.3 install pylint

or

sudo apt install pylint3
```

If none of that works out, here's a thread you can refer to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/340940/installing-pylint-for-python3-on-ubuntu

Comment: I can use PIP. I can even manually update PIP. 

On my laptop pylint works, but somehow it does not work on my desktop machine. Both machines use Windows 10. 

I even tried to update to Python 3.91 today and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe try to run those commands on your WSL. Or update whatever Linux distro you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Get Chocolatey on windows.

then try

choco install python

choco install pip

Comment: I already have PIP version 20.3.1 installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Installing "wheel" (pip install wheel) somehow resolved this.

Is there an explanation? On my desktop I did not have this issue. That's why I am kinda confused since I am new to Python.